# Storing $_Post values to array in php

Tags: php, arrays

Sorry I don't know how to explain it in title so I just explain it here.

So I have this html and I want to store this in array, this is the code below

```
<tr>
<td>
<input name="grade_id[]" value="4" type="hidden">
</td>
<td>
<input name="q1_grade[]">94</input>
</td>
<td>
<input name="q2_grade[]">89</input>
</td>
<td>
<input name="q3_grade[]">90</input>
</td>
<td>
<input name="q4_grade[]">88</input>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<input name="grade_id[]" value="7" type="hidden">
</td>
<td>
<input name="q1_grade[]">95</input>
</td>
<td>
<input name="q2_grade[]">77</input>
</td>
<td>
<input name="q3_grade[]">77</input>
</td>
<td>
<input name="q4_grade[]">98</input>
</td>
</tr>
```

Now from above code I want to manipulate the datas in an array so I put the data specifically in array which the `id` has its own `$q1 $q2 $q3 $q4` to do this is as per code below

```
<?php
 $grade_idArray = $_POST['grade_id'];
 $q1_gradesArray = $_POST['q1_grade'];
 $q2_gradesArray = $_POST['q2_grade'];
 $q3_gradesArray = $_POST['q3_grade']; 
 $q4_gradesArray = $_POST['q4_grade'];

 $grade = array();
 $gf = array();

 foreach($grade_idArray as $g)
 {
    foreach($q1_gradesArray as $q1)
    {
      foreach($q2_gradesArray as $q2)
      {
        foreach($q3_gradesArray as $q3)
        {
            foreach($q4_gradesArray as $q4)
            {
                $grade = array($g,$q1,$q2,$q3,$q4);
            }
        }
      }
    }
  }

 echo var_dump($grade);
 ?>
```

But the output data that I am receiving is just one array instead of two arrays. how should i do it?

```
array(5) { [0]=> string(2) "7" [1]=> string(2) "95" [2]=> string(2) "77" [3]=> string(2) "77" [4]=> string(2) "98" }
```

Comment: Its values are getting from its database. I don't know any other option to store them in an array. My goal here is to update the inputs. Is there any efficient way I can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way. May be it would be helpful for you.

```
foreach($grade_idArray as $key => $g)
 {
    $grade[$key] = [$g, $q1_gradesArray[$key], $q2_gradesArray[$key], 
    $q3_gradesArray[$key], $q4_gradesArray[$key]]
}
echo var_dump($grade);
```